# Fechar libreoffice writer via terminal no Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice

qual comando posso utilizar para fechar o libreoffice writer via terminal no ubuntu?
Obrigado.

Comment: `kill -9 <ID-DO-PROCESSO>`. Para capturar o id use `ps aux | grep libre`. Ou utilize `killall <Nome-do-processo>`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr por esse comando `ps aux | grep libre` que me passou consegui encontrar o caminho do libreoffice e usei o seguinte comando `killall /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin` para fechar e deu certo, Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta usar o seguinte comando

```
ps aux | grep -i office | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

Ou a versão mais curta

```
kill -9 `pgrep -lf soffice.bin | awk {'print $1'}`
```